# Unreasonable amount of time to query view in EF 6

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

This takes about 6 seconds in Management Studio with cleared cache.

```
          SELECT
          [TransactionSum].[AccountID] AS [AccountID],
          [TransactionSum].[Balance] AS [Balance],
          [TransactionSum].[ReservedAmount] AS [ReservedAmount]
          FROM [dbo].[TransactionSum] AS [TransactionSum]
          WHERE [AccountID] = 34626
```

The view is quite complex with 5 nested subqueries. In fact it takes about 6 seconds to run without the where clause, returning 11000 lines.

So how can this

```
DB.TransactionSum.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AccountID == 34626);
```

or this

```
var args = new DbParameter[] { new SqlParameter 
      { ParameterName = "accountid", Value = 34626 } };

DB.ExecuteStoreQuery<TransactionSum>("SELECT " +
     "AccountID," +
     "Balance," +
     "ReservedAmount " +
     "FROM TransactionSum " +
     "WHERE AccountID = @accountid", args).SingleOrDefault();
```

take over 3 minutes? CPU is maxed throughout. I can see the rendered sql using  sys.dm_exec_sql_text. I ran that in 6 seconds.

**Edit**

@clifton_h suggestion worked. After wrapping the view in a sproc

```
BoinkDB.ExecuteStoreQuery<TransactionSum>("exec spTransactionSum "+ accountID);
```

was really fast.

(Numerous variants of passing parameters the way your supposed to, failed. I'm not sure about anything now, but I believe that's beside the point.)

I have no idea what's going on. How can EF f*k up 
`DB.TransactionSum.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AccountID == 34626);` so badly as to increase query time with several orders? Is it telling the server to optimize its query plan by sampling the whole integer space every time I call it?

What sort of implicit optimization does Management Studio do or does implicitly create a sproc each time I run a query? And still, why would that help as it obvously does?

Those look to me even like stupid questions but I am just utterly bewildered at the moment. What I've been reading about parameter sniffing is all about optimization, tweaking, shaving of fractions of seconds. We're talking orders of magnitude.

Actually, what would be helpfull was if somebody could show me how I can make a query from Management Studio take over 3 minutes!

**Edit 2**

Yes, that was helpful. This

```
declare @accountid int
set @accountid =34626

SELECT
[TransactionSum].[AccountID] AS [AccountID],
[TransactionSum].[Balance] AS [Balance],
[TransactionSum].[ReservedAmount] AS [ReservedAmount]
FROM [dbo].[TransactionSum] AS [TransactionSum]
WHERE [AccountID] = @accountid
```

took 1 minute 20.

So, according to my fresh understanding of parameter sniffing, the optimizer uses 34626 to create an optimum query plan, but then use 34626 to actually run it which... no, I still don't get it.

Comment: Search parameter sniffing. You assume the initualization of variables in SQL Server occurs the same time as the script, but it is not. Also, try not to call straight strings into your proc.

Comment: For now I'm happy to solve the problem AccountID=34626. That should take less than 10 seconds, which is the time it takes for the uncached complete query, plus generous network overhead.

Comment: You misunderstand me...parameter sniffing is your problem. The optimizer is unable to guess at the query values of histograms because it sees your variable as an unknown variable at compile time.

Comment: I'm sure I am. Is the query optimizer taking 2 minutes and 54 seconds? There is no proc. I introduced the straight string when debugging what was taking so long. I read this https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/. I don't understand how to solve the problem because it's about different parameters and I'm using the same one.

Comment: What I would try to do is to create a Stored Procedure that calls your view. Then call that stored procedure from your EF. That stored procedure can then utilize one of anti-paramater sniffing methods.

Comment: The message is: try to execute the query in SSMS using a variable `@accountId` instead of `= 34626`. You should see a similar difference.

Comment: Thanks! Please see edit 2.

Comment: Parameter sniffing is a quite complex issue, and the combinations of technologies (Entity Framework) only helps obscure it that much more. It's easier to cope with when calling stored procedures (optimize for unknown, local parameter, recompile etc) - but the symptom is almost always the same; Slow in code layer, fast in SSMS and the execution difference can be quite significant (as you've seen yourself)

Comment: Well I thank you all for your knowledgeable help.

Comment: Glad we all could help. Just remember it is how SQL Server sees the query, not how you write it that matters. Hopefully, this helps you to ask more "how do i know what I know?" questions when developing code...not just SQL Server. Unlike C++, for example, SQL Server does not have a constant @variable. Therefore, you need to ensure this by encapsulation that calls the proc. On the flip side, writing out the script without the proc sees the correct results since SQL Server is able to compile the script normally, whereas in a proc it is unable to.

Comment: Think of it like simply initializing a variable without setting its value does for C++ (and other OOP): the value is not constant from run time to run time. Similarly, SQL Server is unable to guess the variables in much the same way, so it cannot use any indexes and must guess wildly. Odd, no? Languages are interesting and teach you new things everytime. Cheers.